# InfoWindow's subDescription will go out of bounds of the bubble in osmdroid bonuspack

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I am trying to set a `subDescription` for my markers with a code like this:

```
Marker marker = new Marker(map);
marker.setPosition(tempGeoPoint);
marker.setIcon(markerIcon);
marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
marker.setSubDescription("lat : " + points.get(i).get(0) + ", long : "
                        + points.get(i).get(1));
marker.setTitle("this is a title");
overlays.add(marker);
```

But this is what I get I get:

[image]

as you can see the sub description is out of bounds and the bubble won't expand to contain it. What are my options here?

PS: The bubble won't expand at all, neither with a sub description nor with a long `snippet`

Comment: why cant you try infowindow ?

Comment: Surprising. I also use subdescriptions, sometimes with carriage returns to get multiple lines, and the bubble grows as needed. Your font is not the default one: did you customized the layout?